# JQuery UI Slider not working after textbox it updates is changed. (ASP.Net)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, slider

I've got a test ASP.Net page, where I've got a textbox and a slider next to it:

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td>Total Monthly Expenses</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtExpenses" Columns="6" Text="$20" /></td>
        <td align="center"> <div id="sliExpenses" class="slider" /></td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

I've initialized the slider in the head:

```
  <script>
      $(function () {
          $("#sliExpenses").slider({
            animate: true
            , min: 10 
            , max: 100 
            , step: 10
            , value: $("#txtExpenses").val().replace("$", "").replace(",", "")
            , change: function (event, ui) {
                $("#txtExpenses").attr('value', "$" + ui.value);
            }
          });
      });
  </script>
```

When the page first loads, the slider works fine. you move it, and the textbox gets updated. If I change the value in the textbox then try the slider, the slider no longer updates the value in the textbox. I've tried the slide, change, and stop functions, and they all have the same problem.

Comment: Should there not be a `;` at the end of here: `value: $("#txtExpenses").val().replace("$", "").replace(",", "");`

Comment: @Andrew - no, it's used as a value. adding a semicolon will actually invalidate the code

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle to a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7CwL/

You should be setting the value of a textbox using a .val() function

```
$("#txtExpenses").val("$" + ui.value);
```